# Text match by pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to implement a function that detects if certain pattern occurs in a script of dialog. The pattern could be a complex one. For example:

`pattern1 = {"Could", "Can", "May", "Do you think"} before {"have", "buy", "enjoy"}`

This pattern will search through texts and find all similar expressions like these:

`Could I have a slice of pizza?
Can you buy me a cup of coffee?
Do you think I can finish this task alone?`

And these I would define another pattern:

`pattern2 = {"Why not", "Sure", "Certainly", "Of course", "Yes"} after pattern1`

And this pattern2 will very likely match texts that two people are talking about if one can do something. The `before` and `after` are positional matching keywords that I would like to have. Other positional relationship I would like to have are `near`(two sub-patterns occured closely), `by(speaker)` (matches the beginning of sentence which indicates the speaker).

I would like to have these patterns defined in a separate files so they are more manageable. I have looked at ANTLR but looks like it is more like defining a new language rather than helping me compile the regex or "matching engine". Could anyone shed some light on how I should proceed this task?

Comment: [`/\b(Could|Can|May|Do you think)\b.*?\b(have|buy|enjoy)\b.*?(?:[?!.])/`](https://regex101.com/r/XlJlNI/3) might be a start (I supposed what you call an "expression" ends with a period, exclamation or question mark.)

Comment: @Jeto thank you so much for your quick response. This is definitely a good start. But what if I have a hundred options in one {...}? For example I may put a lot of verbs in one {...} to catch a dialog about a physical action.

Comment: Well you'd probably have to dynamically build the pattern using whichever programming language you're using :)